# Excel: is there a function that returns a range for satisfying the matching condition?

Tags: excel

Given a value compare with the subsequent rows (on the same column) and return the range upto the row where the value changes for the first time.

```
Example:
   A
1  cat
2  cat
3  cat
4  dog
5  cat
```

The range to be returned is A1:A3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have cat in cell `c1`, the following formula will return the first continuous matching range. Enter with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

`=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1:A5,MATCH(C1,A1:A5,0)-1,0,MATCH(TRUE,OFFSET(A1:A5,MATCH(C1,A1:A5,0),0)<>C1,0)),"cat")`

If your data always start in A1 and you want the whole range matching the first value, all the way until the next value, use the following array formula (entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,MATCH(TRUE,A:A<>A1,0)-1)
```

Comment: Nutsch, thank you also for the solution you have posted. I do not know before hand the value "cat", that I am looking for is within the range of the A1:A5. The range of unknown before hand. When I am at the Active Row, I want to find out from that row downwards what the range where the first occurence of the value change. The first occurence of the value change in this example is A4. Therefore, the solution should return the cell id A3 or the count of the rows.

Comment: So you always want the cell before the second value?

Comment: Yes. i.e. the range upto the cell before the second value.

Comment: added formula for just the range matching the first value.

Answer (score 1):

This works as an array formula. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> in the formula bar to evaluate it. I have tested it to work on this very simple case. I can't tell about more complex cases:

```
=INDIRECT("A1:A" & MAX(ROW(A1:A5)*(A1:A5="cat")*(A2:A6<>"cat")))
```

Edit: If you really want the range to be returned and not values, you just have to remove the INDIRECT but leave everything else inside it.

Comment: You have specified the range as A1:A5. In the example I have given above, the range you have specified is the case, but I won't know what is the range of the first occurence of the value in the given ActiveRow, Column1. Could you please explain your solution. I tried it out and I don't understand.