# Count distinct occurrences and averages in a column based on identifiers in another column

Tags: excel

In MS Excel, I want to count the number of distinct categories (ignoring a specific item) based on a different column. Also, I want to find the average and the max for the same selection. This is the data:

```
+--------+-----------+-------+
| Person |   idea    | score |
+--------+-----------+-------+
| George | vacuum    |     9 |
| George | box       |     6 |
| George | x         |     1 |
| Joe    | scoop     |     4 |
| Joe    | x         |     1 |
| Joe    | x         |     1 |
| Joe    | scoop     |     4 |
| Joe    | gear      |     7 |
| Mike   | harvester |    10 |
| Mike   | gear      |     7 |
| Mike   | box       |     6 |
+--------+-----------+-------+
```

The result should be the following:

```
+--------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| Person | distinct ideas | Avg. score | Max score |
+--------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| George |              2 | 5.3        |         9 |
| Joe    |              2 | 3.4        |         7 |
| Mike   |              3 | 7.7        |        10 |
+--------+----------------+------------+-----------+
```

Because Joe has two "scoop" and one "gear" idea, and I want to ignore the "x" items.
I reluctantly gave up and did it manually for each person, e.g., this is for the first person:

```
SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B2:B4,B2:B4,0),MATCH(B2:B4,B2:B4,0))>0,1))-IF(COUNTIF(B2:B4,"x")>0,1,0)
```

Doesn't Excel have functions to return a range instead of a value? If I could select the range based on the name of the person in the first columns, I could count distinct occurrences or find the average in another column.

Comment: something like offset? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188569/excel-is-there-a-function-that-returns-a-range-for-satisfying-the-matching-cond

Comment: Sorry, for the mistake; "pump" should have been "gear". The "x" items are ignored in counting the ideas; but I give them a low score which I want to be reflected in the average, so that condition doesn't apply.

Comment: @mdinar But why George average 5.3 if ignoring 'x'?

Comment: Why are you not using pivottables for this? First of all it will solve all your problems, and second, if you don't use it yet, a new world opens.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I want to ignore "x" only when counting distinct items; but I want to keep it in the score average.

Comment: @mdinar What version of Excel are you working with?

Comment: @Riverside I don't know about them; I'll take a look. Thanks. Sometimes I wish I could write SQL queries in Excel! But this was a bit urgent. I went through the hassle of making the selections manually for 10 subjects; I don't wanna do it for the other 20.

Comment: I made a pivot of the above within 2 minutes. However you take the average including the X's. That might not be correct. But I think pivots will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 4th column and label it Distinct Ideas
If your table starts in A1, then:

**EDIT:** Formula changed to exclude "x". Screen shot also changed

```
D2:  =IF(TRIM($B2)="x",0,IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1))
```

and fill down.

Then construct a Pivot table

- Person to Row Labels
- Distinct Ideas to Values area
- score to Values and select to Average
- Score to Values area and Select Max

Format as desired.  Here is one result:

[image]

Comment: The distinct ideas you found consider "x" items too. How do I deduct them (-1 when "x" exists in selection)

Comment: I just noticed that error.  Will correct in my answer

Comment: Two things: 
1) when I move "distinct ideas", it appears as a sum which gives the wrong answer. What should I change it to?
2) the "ideas" are not sorted. So in your formula, when you encounter a repeated item that is different from the rows before it, it adds 1 which if I use in the sum as above, gives me the wrong answer. In the data I gave, switch the second "Joe scoop" with "Joe gear"; I think your answer will change.

Comment: Of course, I can sort that column and then run the formula. But I wanted to make it robust. Thanks.

Comment: @mdinar What do you mean by "move"? The formula I provided does not depend on anything being sorted. And when I "switch" the two Joe's as you state, I see no change in the Pivot table.  In your downloaded data, there are leading and trailing spaces around the ideas. Are you taking that into account in your testing?  There is a difference between " scoop     " and "scoop".  They are not the same.

Comment: The table I provided was redacted from my data just as an example. I am sure my data is trimmed and doesn't have any spaces.

Comment: By move I meant, step 2 of 4 that you listed. When I drag "distinct ideas" and drop it in "Values" area, it appears as Sum of Distinct ideas.

Comment: As it should.  What is the problem?  As I wrote, the data that you provided (trim'd), gives the result you provided.

Comment: Since I was doing this for multiple columns, I had to expand it; I forgot to change the A2 in the first part of the SUMPRODUCT to $A2, this worked: `=IF(TRIM(B2)="x",0,IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=$A2)*(B$2:B2=B2))>1,0,1))`